# How can I read txt file in android?

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.popword;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadText1 extends Activity {
    TextView textview;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\UOU\\Desktop\\word.txt"))) {
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                textview.setText(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Exception occurred!");
        }
    }
}
```

===================================================================================
    2019-11-13 20:07:44.224 1004-1004/com.example.popword E/cklee: com.example.popword.ReadText1.printStackTrace(ReadText1.java:29)
        com.example.popword.ReadText1.onCreate(ReadText1.java:22)
        android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Please share your stacktrace (Exception) in the log so that we know exactly which type of exception is being thrown. Add e.printStackTrace(); into your catch block and post the console log output.

Comment: `C:\\Users\\UOU\\Desktop\\word.txt` is not a file on your Android device/emulator. It's on your development machine. You cannot directly read that from an Android app.

Comment: don't ignore the exceoption, at least do `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0):

You need tu put your txt file inside Android project package.
You can put it in :

- **Assets folder** then :

> ```
> AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
> InputStream is = am.open("word.txt");
> ```

- **Res folder** ( res/raw ) then :

> InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.word);

Answer (score 0):

How can you read a file that is located on your computer?
And there are lots of tutorials in the web explaining you how to read and write to files in android. And I would use BufferedReader instead of Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly read file from storage or sdcard follow below step:

1.Add these two permission to your project manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

2.Create below function

```
private void ReadTxtFile(File txtfilepath) {
    if (txtfilepath.exists()) {
        StringBuffer txt = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfilepath));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                txt.append(line);
                txt.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception:",e.toString());
        }

        Log.e("File Text:",txt.toString());// "txt" variable contian your file text
    }
}
```

3. Call function wherever you want and provide text file path as function parameter

   ```
    ReadTxtFile(new File("/sdcard/Download/sample.txt"));
   ```